# Show a specific text in another file in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, text

I would like to do the following: I have a file in which I can select a product. If the product has been selected (is it true) and the costs should be displayed on another page (with TabView). The problem is that I don't know how to access the variable in the other file.

I have already tried the following:

-if file.init(variable: true){…}
->Error

-if variable == true {…} ->Error

-Text(file.init(variable)

And the image will help you to understand me.
[Link to the Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnwYH.jpg)

I hope  you are the best in swift and can help me!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post text, not images. And please describe more in detail what you are going to accomplish. And add more code for example the code related to the tab view.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. E.g. try to post a [mre]. Also reading [ask] may help you improve your question.